# Populating a cell with data from one sheet based on if another sheet cell contains a certain value

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets-formula, gsheets

I would like a cell in Sheet3 to populate with data from Sheet2 IF data from sheet1 contains a specific value.

I have tried:

=IF('Sheet1'!A1="Yes",'Sheet3'!A1='Sheet2'!A1,"")

I was hoping that this formula would input data from Sheet2 A1 into Sheet3 A1 based on the value being "Yes" from Sheet1 A1. If not, it would leave the cell blank.

I feel like the solution is simple and perhaps it's not even an IF statement solution but I'm very new to this!

Answer (score 0):

In `Sheet3!A1` try entering:

```
=IF(
    'Sheet1'!A1="Yes",
    'Sheet2'!A1,
    "")
```

You don’t need to specify that you want to set Sheet3!A1 equal to the value in Sheet2!A1, you do that simply by entering the formula into Sheet3!A1.